# ignore a user defined exception in oracle

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql, defined

In pl/sql I have some inner begin, end blocks and "Exception Others" blocks.
When I throw my user defined exception from an inner block I just want to catch this exception in the last "Exception userdef" block, not in the inner "Exception Others" blocks. 
Any idea?

Comment: Why are you using `WHEN OTHERS` exception handlers?  Why aren't you catching just the specific exceptions that you can actually handle?

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried? It will probably help explain your problem better.

Comment: @Justin, i already know some ways to solve the issue. I just wonder whether it is possible with less code or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have something like this:

```
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    BEGIN
      DO_SOMETHING;  -- raises USERDEF_EXCEPTION 
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DIE_HORRIBLY;
    END;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      DIE_EVEN_MORE_HORRIBLY;
  END;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN USERDEF_EXCEPTION THEN
    DO_SOMETHING_REASONABLE;
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DIE_INCREDIBLY_HORRIBLY;
END;
```

and you want to DO_SOMETHING_REASONABLE rather than DIE_HORRIBLY or DIE_EVEN_MORE_HORRIBLY.  Sorry - you can't do that without providing a handler in the inner blocks for your exception.  You'll have to do something like:

```
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    BEGIN
      DO_SOMETHING;  -- raises USERDEF_EXCEPTION 
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN USERDEF_EXCEPTION THEN
        RAISE;
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DIE_HORRIBLY;
    END;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN USERDEF_EXCEPTION THEN
      RAISE;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      DIE_EVEN_MORE_HORRIBLY;
  END;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN USERDEF_EXCEPTION THEN
    DO_SOMETHING_REASONABLE;
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DIE_INCREDIBLY_HORRIBLY;
END;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: You say just catch the exception in the inner block and throw again... I know that solution,  I wonder if it is possible with less code...

Comment: Given the situation you described, where code in the inner-most block throws a user-defined exception, each nested block has a `WHEN OTHERS` handler, and you want to handle your user-defined exception only in the outer block, I can't think of another way to do this.  I suppose in the inner `WHEN OTHERS` handlers you could check for your particular SQLCODE value and re-raise it, but I think that's even more of a kluge than what I suggested above.  Basically, there's no way I know of to create a handler which will "Handle all errors *except* one I don't want handled".  Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* package */
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE exceptions_pkg AS
    user_defined_exception EXCEPTION;
END exceptions_pkg;

/* block */
DECLARE
    l_var1 NUMBER;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('one');

    DECLARE
        l_var2 NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('two');

        IF 1 < 2 THEN
            RAISE exceptions_pkg.user_defined_exception;
        END IF;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('three');
    END;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('four');
EXCEPTION
    WHEN exceptions_pkg.user_defined_exception THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('five');
END;

-- anonymous block completed
/*
one
two
five
*/
```